# ≡-Reasoning and 'with' patterns

Tags: agda

I was proving some properties of `filter` and `map`, everything went quite good until I stumbled on this property: `filter p (map f xs) ≡ map f (filter (p ∘ f) xs)`. Here's a part of the code that's relevant:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Bool
open import Data.List hiding (filter)

import Level

filter : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → (A → Bool) → List A → List A
filter _ [] = []
filter p (x ∷ xs) with p x
... | true  = x ∷ filter p xs
... | false = filter p xs
```

Now, because I love writing proofs using the `≡-Reasoning` module, the first thing I tried was:

```
open ≡-Reasoning
open import Function

filter-map : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : Set b}
             (xs : List A) (f : A → B) (p : B → Bool) →
             filter p (map f xs) ≡ map f (filter (p ∘ f) xs)
filter-map []       _ _ = refl
filter-map (x ∷ xs) f p with p (f x)
... | true = begin
  filter p (map f (x ∷ xs))
    ≡⟨ refl ⟩
  f x ∷ filter p (map f xs)
--  ...
```

But alas, that didn't work. After trying for one hour, I finally gave up and proved it in this way:

```
filter-map (x ∷ xs) f p with p (f x)
... | true  = cong (λ a → f x ∷ a) (filter-map xs f p)
... | false = filter-map xs f p
```

Still curious about why going through `≡-Reasoning` didn't work, I tried something very trivial:

```
filter-map-def : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : Set b}
                 (x : A) xs (f : A → B) (p : B → Bool) → T (p (f x)) →
                 filter p (map f (x ∷ xs)) ≡ f x ∷ filter p (map f xs)
filter-map-def x xs f p _  with p (f x)
filter-map-def x xs f p () | false
filter-map-def x xs f p _  | true = -- not writing refl on purpose
  begin
    filter p (map f (x ∷ xs))
  ≡⟨ refl ⟩
    f x ∷ filter p (map f xs)
  ∎
```

But typechecker doesn't agree with me. It would seem that the current goal remains `filter p (f x ∷ map f xs) | p (f x)` and even though I pattern matched on `p (f x)`, `filter` just won't reduce to `f x ∷ filter p (map f xs)`.

Is there a way to make this work with `≡-Reasoning`?

Thanks!

Comment: revisiting a similar issue : so "inspect on steroid" or "rewrite" are the blessed way ?

Comment: @nicolas: I think they are in fact the only way (don't forget that `rewrite` is just a `with`).

Comment: thank you. for reference to future interested readers, I found those videos which have been quite informative by chris jenkins :  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCC84u-u6xRFQQd6wu33NfDw

Answer (score 6):

The trouble with `with`-clauses is that Agda forgets the information it learned from pattern match unless you arrange beforehand for this information to be preserved.

More precisely, when Agda sees a `with expression` clause, it replaces all the occurences of `expression` in the current context and goal with a fresh variable `w` and then gives you that variable with updated context and goal into the with-clause, forgetting everything about its origin.

In your case, you write `filter p (map f (x ∷ xs))` inside the with-block, so it goes into scope after Agda has performed the rewriting, so Agda has already forgotten the fact that `p (f x)` is `true` and does not reduce the term.

You can preserve the proof of equality by using one of the "Inspect"-patterns from the standard library, but I'm not sure how it can be useful in your case.

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I suspected. `inspect` was the first thing that came to my mind but it somehow doesn't seem to fit anywhere. Thanks for answering!