# Using an equivalence in the context to force reduction

Tags: pattern-matching, proof, reduction, agda, equivalence

The setting for this question is the same "merge of sorted lists" example from this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564911/merge-of-sorted-lists-with-sized-types).

```
{-# OPTIONS --sized-types #-}

open import Relation.Binary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as P hiding (trans)

module ListMerge
   { ℓ}
   (A : Set )
   {_<_ : Rel A ℓ}
   (isStrictTotalOrder : IsStrictTotalOrder _≡_ _<_) where

   open import Data.Product
   open import Data.Unit
   open import Level
   open import Size

   data SortedList (l u : A) : {ι : Size} → Set ( ⊔ ℓ) where
      [] : {ι : _} → .(l < u) → SortedList l u {↑ ι}
      _∷[_]_ : {ι : _} (x : A) → .(l < x) → (xs : SortedList x u {ι}) →
               SortedList l u {↑ ι}
```

As before, I'm using sized types so that Agda can determine that the following `merge` function terminates:

```
   open IsStrictTotalOrder isStrictTotalOrder

   merge : ∀ {l u} → {ι : _} → SortedList l u {ι} →
                      {ι′ : _} → SortedList l u {ι′} → SortedList l u
   merge xs ([] _) = xs
   merge ([] _) ys = ys
   merge (x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (y ∷[ l<y ] ys) with compare x y
   ... | tri< _ _ _ = x ∷[ l<x ] (merge xs (y ∷[ _ ] ys))
   merge (x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (.x ∷[ _ ] ys) | tri≈ _ P.refl _ =
      x ∷[ l<x ] (merge xs ys)
   ... | tri> _ _ _ = y ∷[ l<y ] (merge (x ∷[ _ ] xs) ys)
```

What I'm trying to do is prove the following associativity theorem:

```
   assoc : ∀ {l u} → {ι₁ : _} → (x : SortedList l u {ι₁}) →
                     {ι₂ : _} → (y : SortedList l u {ι₂}) →
                     {ι₃ : _} → (z : SortedList l u {ι₃}) →
           merge (merge x y) z ≡ merge x (merge y z)
```

The cases where at least one list is `[]` follow easily by definition, but I'll include them for completeness.

```
   assoc ([] _) ([] _) ([] _) = P.refl
   assoc ([] _) ([] _) (_ ∷[ _ ] _) = P.refl
   assoc ([] _) (_ ∷[ _ ] _) ([] _) = P.refl
   assoc (_ ∷[ _ ] _) ([] _) ([] _) = P.refl
   assoc ([] _) (y ∷[ _ ] _) (z ∷[ _ ] _) with compare y z
   assoc ([] _) (y ∷[ _ ] ys) (.y ∷[ _ ] zs) | tri≈ _ P.refl _ = P.refl
   ... | tri< _ _ _ = P.refl
   ... | tri> _ _ _ = P.refl
   assoc (x ∷[ _ ] _) ([] _) (z ∷[ _ ] _) with compare x z
   assoc (x ∷[ _ ] xs) ([] _) (.x ∷[ _ ] zs) | tri≈ _ P.refl _ = P.refl
   ... | tri< _ _ _ = P.refl
   ... | tri> _ _ _ = P.refl
   assoc (x ∷[ _ ] _) (y ∷[ _ ] _) ([] _) with compare x y
   assoc (x ∷[ _ ] xs) (.x ∷[ _ ] ys) ([] _) | tri≈ _ P.refl _ = P.refl
   ... | tri< _ _ _ = P.refl
   ... | tri> _ _ _ = P.refl
```

However, I'm getting stuck trying to prove the remaining case, which has many sub-cases. In particular, I don't know how to "reuse" facts such as `compare x y ≡ tri< .a .¬b .¬c` inside proof contexts beneath the top level (without, say, introducing an auxiliary lemma).

I'm aware of, and have had some success with, the `inspect` (on steroids) idiom mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320052/reasoning-and-with-patterns), but my problem seems to be that the context in which I want to "reuse" the relevant fact isn't yet established when I use `rewrite` to simplify with the equality I've saved using `inspect`.

So for example in the following sub-case, I can capture the values of `compare x y` and `compare y z` using the following `inspect` calls:

```
   assoc (x ∷[ _ ] _) (y ∷[ _ ] _) (z ∷[ _ ] _)
         with compare x y | compare y z
         | P.inspect (hide (compare x) y) unit
         | P.inspect (hide (compare y) z) unit
```

and then `rewrite` to simplify:

```
   assoc {l} {u} (x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (y ∷[ _ ] ys) (.y ∷[ _ ] zs)
         | tri< _ _ _ | tri≈ _ P.refl _ | P.[ eq ] | P.[ eq′ ] rewrite eq | eq′ =
```

But I think the `rewrite` will only affect the goal which is active at that point. In particular, if in the body of the proof I use `cong` to shift into a nested context which permits more reduction, I may expose new occurrences of those comparisons which will not have been rewritten. (See the `{!!}` below for the location I mean.) My understanding of exactly how reduction proceeds is a little hazy, so I'd welcome any correction or clarification on this.

```
      begin
         x ∷[ _ ] merge (merge xs (y ∷[ _ ] ys)) (y ∷[ _ ] zs)
      ≡⟨ P.cong (λ xs → x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (assoc xs (y ∷[ _ ] ys) (y ∷[ _ ] zs)) ⟩
         x ∷[ _ ] merge xs (merge (y ∷[ _ ] ys) (y ∷[ _ ] zs))
      ≡⟨ P.cong (λ xs′ → x ∷[ _ ] merge xs xs′)
                {merge (y ∷[ _ ] ys) (y ∷[ _ ] zs)} {y ∷[ _ ] merge ys zs} {!!} ⟩
         x ∷[ _ ] merge xs (y ∷[ _ ] merge ys zs)
      ∎ where open import Relation.Binary.EqReasoning (P.setoid (SortedList l u))
```

(The implicit arguments to `cong` need to be made explicit here.)

When I put the cursor in the hole, I can see that the goal (somewhat paraphrased) is

```
merge (y ∷[ _ ] ys) (y ∷[ _ ] zs) | compare y y ≡ y ∷[ _ ] merge ys zs
```

despite the earlier `rewrite eq′`. Moreover in my context I have

```
eq′  : compare y y ≡ tri≈ .¬a refl .¬c
```

which seems to be exactly what I need to allow reduction to make progress so that `refl` will complete the proof-case.

Here's the placeholder for the remaining sub-cases.

```
   assoc (x ∷[ _ ] _) (_ ∷[ _ ] _) (z ∷[ _ ] _) | _ | _ | _ | _ = {!!}
```

I'm a little unconfident here; I don't know whether I'm misusing `inspect` on steroids, going about the proof the wrong way entirely, or just being stupid.

Is there a way to use the `eq′` equivalence from the context to allow reduction to proceed?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. You will have to pattern match on `compare y y` again and show that the other two cases cannot happen.

Comment: Right, thanks. I suppose I can see why things are that way, although it bumps up the level of boilerplate considerably. It seems I also have to duplicate the `inspect (hide (compare y) z)` code too; even when I've eliminated the impossible cases, I can't just `rewrite` using the information already in the context without getting an ill-formed desugaring (`w != compare y z of type Tri (y < z) (y ≡ z) (z < y) when checking that the type ... of the generated with function is well-formed`).

Comment: Actually it turned out that I didn't need those nested uses of `inspect` after all (see lemmas below), so that particular issue didn't arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as per [Vitus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/700253/vitus)' comment, one needs to pattern-match again on the outcome of the comparison. I ended up defining 3 helper lemmas, one for each branch of the trichotomy, and then using each lemma twice in the final proof.

```
merge≡ : ∀ {x l u} (l<x : l < x) {ι₁ : _} (xs : SortedList x u {ι₁}) {ι₂ : _} (ys : SortedList x u {ι₂}) →
         merge (x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (x ∷[ l<x ] ys) ≡ x ∷[ l<x ] merge xs ys
merge≡ {x} _ _ _ with compare x x
merge≡ _ _ _ | tri< _ x≢x _ = ⊥-elim (x≢x refl)
merge≡ _ _ _ | tri≈ _ refl _ = refl
merge≡ _ _ _ | tri> _ x≢x _ = ⊥-elim (x≢x refl)

merge< : ∀ {x y l u} (l<x : l < x) (l<y : l < y) (x<y : x < y)
         {ι₁ : _} (xs : SortedList x u {ι₁}) {ι₂ : _} (ys : SortedList y u {ι₂}) →
         merge (x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (y ∷[ l<y ] ys) ≡ x ∷[ l<x ] merge xs (y ∷[ x<y ] ys)
merge< {x} {y} _ _ _ _ _ with compare x y
merge< _ _ _ _ _ | tri< _ _ _ = refl
merge< _ _ x<y _ _ | tri≈ x≮y _ _ = ⊥-elim (x≮y x<y)
merge< _ _ x<y _ _ | tri> x≮y _ _ = ⊥-elim (x≮y x<y)

merge> : ∀ {x y l u} (l<x : l < x) (l<y : l < y) (y<x : y < x)
         {ι₁ : _} (xs : SortedList x u {ι₁}) {ι₂ : _} (ys : SortedList y u {ι₂}) →
         merge (x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (y ∷[ l<y ] ys) ≡ y ∷[ l<y ] merge (x ∷[ y<x ] xs) ys
merge> {x} {y} _ _ _ _ _ with compare x y
merge> _ _ y<x _ _ | tri< _ _ y≮x = ⊥-elim (y≮x y<x)
merge> _ _ y<x _ _ | tri≈ _ _ y≮x = ⊥-elim (y≮x y<x)
merge> _ _ _ _ _ | tri> _ _ _ = refl
```

Still, this is an unsatisfying amount of boilerplate; I'm guessing (with little first-hand experience) that Coq would fare better.

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work! :) By the way, instead of `with x≮y x<y; ... | ()`, you can use `⊥-elim` from `Data.Empty`: `= ⊥-elim (x≮y x<y)`.

Comment: Updated answer to use ⊥-elim.